# SVG doesn't render all objects after modification with Javascript or D3.js [RESOLVED]

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add a parent element (group or "g" tag) to some circles in an SVG.  The code appears to work correctly and the DOM shows the new parent element in the correct place. However the browser doesn't physically render the new version of the SVG despite the DOM appearing to be correct.

Here is the SVG I'm trying to add group elements to:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
   <ellipse class="blueDot" cx="140" cy="35" rx="30" ry="30" id="dot1"/>
   <ellipse class="blueDot" cx="80" cy="60" rx="30" ry="30" id="dot2"/>
   <ellipse class="blueDot group" cx="180" cy="120" rx="30" ry="30" id="dot3" />
   <ellipse class="blueDot group" cx="40" cy="180" rx="30" ry="30" id="dot4" />
   <ellipse class="blueDot group" cx="220" cy="220" rx="30" ry="30" id="dot5" />
</svg>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("ellipse.group").each(function(){
      console.log("Grouping: " + this.id);
    
    var oldParent = this.parentNode;
    var newParent = document.createElement('g');
    oldParent.replaceChild(newParent, this);
    newParent.appendChild(this);
});
```

The resulting DOM is correct:

[image]

...but only the two untouched circles render:

[image]

Do I need to "refresh" or "repaint" somehow?

[Here's my current code in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmg196/h1dcqmw8/)

**EDIT:**  OK thanks for the tips. This code works:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("ellipse.group").each(function(){
      console.log("Grouping: " + this.id);
    
    var oldParent = this.parentNode;
    var newParent = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g"); // CHANGED LINE
    oldParent.replaceChild(newParent, this);
    newParent.appendChild(this);
});
```

Comment: You need to create the <g> in the SVG NameSpace, not in the HTML NameSpace: ``createElementNS``

Comment: On top of what was said above, you could do everything here with d3 methods, which internally take care of the namespace for you.